# Operation of "List" object in rcpp

Tags: r, list, rcpp

I'm sure about some operations of `List` objects in Rcpp, such as getting the number of elements and referring to the ith element, etc... Code like the following, where `X` here is a `List` of matrices with the same number of rows.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h> 
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace arma;
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;
using namespace sugar;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List Test_C(mat Y, List X){       
  int K = X.n_elem; //I was trying to get the # of elems of X
  mat X1 = X[1];    //I was trying to get the first matrix in X
  mat YX1 = [Y, X1]; //I was trying to combine Y and X1 to one matrix.
  List out;
  out["K"] = K;
  out["X1"] = X1;
  out["YX1"] = YX1;
  return(out);
}
```

I sourced this code and called it in R: (`Y` and `X` are well defined in R)

```
Test_C(Y, X);
```

but apparently something is wrong.

Comment: I'm a little confused about whether your question pertains to (1) joining an `arma::mat` with the elements of an `Rcpp::List`, as your title indicates; or (2) finding the number of elements in (?) / length of (?) an `Rcpp::List`, as you note in your answer below. Can you please clarify this?

Comment: My X is a list consists of matrices, I want to know how many matrices in X (i.e., how many elements in the list). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your ultimate goal was to generalize the joining of `Y` with all of the matrices in `X`, so that's how I approached the problem below:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h> 
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

struct fill_from_list {
  fill_from_list(const arma::mat& init)
    : x(init) {}
  void operator()(const arma::mat& m) {
    x = arma::join_rows(x, m);
  }
  arma::mat x;
};

arma::mat accum_join(const arma::mat& init, Rcpp::List X) {
  return std::for_each(X.begin(), X.end(), fill_from_list(init)).x;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List Test_C2(const arma::mat& Y, Rcpp::List X) {
  return Rcpp::List::create(
    Rcpp::Named("K") = X.size(),
    Rcpp::Named("X1") = X[0],
    Rcpp::Named("YXK") = accum_join(Y, X));
}
```

---

To elaborate a bit, the function object `fill_from_list` is constructed with an initial `arma::mat`, and each time an additional `arma::mat` is passed to it via `operator()`, the data member `x` is updated with the input's columns using `arma::join_rows`.

This functor is employed in the helper function `accum_join`, which takes the appropriate input objects and returns an accumulated `arma::mat` by using the `std::for_each` algorithm (*note the trailing `.x` - `for_each` itself does not have a return value*).

The last function just returns a list of the style shown in your question, except that the third element is now the concatenation of `Y` and all of `X`'s elements, rather than `Y` and the first element of `X`.

---

Compared to your original function -

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List Test_C(arma::mat Y, Rcpp::List X){       
  int K = X.size(); 
  arma::mat X1 = X[0];    
  arma::mat YX1 = arma::join_rows(Y, X1); 
  Rcpp::List out;
  out["K"] = K;
  out["X1"] = X1;
  out["YXK"] = YX1;
  return out;
}
```

we have:

```
mlist <- lapply(1:4, function(x) matrix(x, nrow = 3, ncol = x))

> all.equal(Test_C(mlist[[1]], mlist[2]), Test_C2(mlist[[1]], mlist[2]))
[1] TRUE

## including matrices 3 and 4:
> Test_C2(mlist[[1]], mlist[2:4])
$K
[1] 3

$X1
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    2
[2,]    2    2
[3,]    2    2

$YXK
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    2    2    3    3    3    4    4    4     4
[2,]    1    2    2    3    3    3    4    4    4     4
[3,]    1    2    2    3    3    3    4    4    4     4
```

---

And just to clarify on your other question,

> int K = X.n_elem; //I was trying to get the # of elems of X

you want `X.size()` (the `Rcpp::` method), rather than `X.n_elem` (the `arma::` method).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out:

```
mat X1 = X[0];  
mat YX1 = join_rows(Y, X1);
```

are correct, but I still don't know how to get the # of elems of a "List" object. I thought this should be something very basic...